# Zend setting the authorization header for unit testing using PHPUnit

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Recently I tried to test my REST API's using PHPUnit.
I am facing problem to send http authorization header for my test case.
Every time I do that I get an 403 response instead of 200 
Here is my code :

```
<?php
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Headers;
use Zend\Http\Response;

class TrialTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    protected $traceError = true;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
           include 'config/application.config.php'
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        $this->request = new Request();
        $this->getRequest()->setMethod('GET');
        //$headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers;
        //$header = $headers->addHeader($headers->fromString('Authorization:Bearer test'));
        $this->getRequest()->sendHeaders('Authorization:Bearer test');
        //var_dump($headers);
        //$this->getRequest()->setHeaders($header);
        $this->dispatch('/campaign');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
    }
}
```

Kindly help !! where am I going wrong ?

Comment: If you have found the answer to the question please update

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your headers like this:

```
$headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers;
$headers->addHeaderLine('Authorization', 'Bearer test');
$this->request->setHeaders($headers);
```

And you have to make sure that `test` a valid OAuth token otherwise it will never work. I am not so sure if a 4 character token will ever validate correctly...

### UPDATE

I think there is a general problem with your test design. You only set the request object in the controller instance, but the service taking care of authentication has no access to this request object and thus it will not authorize the request correctly.

If you write a controller test in which you test the route `'/campaign'` you should only test the controller functionality and set mocks for all dependencies. I think the main problem starts in your `setUp` method. To test this controller you should not load your whole `application.config.php`. You should set an `MvcEvent` instance and attach all you need to this event (the correct `Router` instance, etc) and then dispatch the controller.

Check a proper example of **[such a ZF2 controller test here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html#your-first-controller-test)**.

Testing your `OAuth` module should happen in an independent test.

Comment: The token 'test' works fine in POSTMAN but while testing in PHPUnit, the error 403 persists.

Comment: @user3341158 I think there is a general problem with your test design. You only set the request object in the controller instance, but the service taking care of authentication has no access to this request object and thus it will not authorize the request correctly.

Comment: OK so what can be done to make the request object accessed by the authentication care taker.

Comment: @user3341158 If you write a controller test you should only test the controller functionality. Check my update.